# Highlighting an area on a mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, geofencing

Google Maps itself can sort of Highlight areas, when you are searching for example for a city. [image: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-H_1aAsFOGks/TxhQNCgz8II/AAAAAAABD_I/Xent-NpuVjM/s640/google-maps-highlight.png]

Since i haven´t found very much via the search function and google....

Is there an intended way to highlight an area (circle or rectangle) on an android mapview Or do i have to go the long way of calculating the necessary size of an picture (for example circle) (which is depending on the zoomlevel) and place it as a mapoverlay, which has to be replaced, whenever the zoom-level changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `Overlay` and override the `draw` method.

For example:

```
class HighlightedAreaOverlay extends Overlay {
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
       super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
       // your drawing code here
    }
}
```

Then add it to your mapView by calling `mapView.getOverlays().add(new HighlightedAreaOverlay());`

Comment: I am getting only ViewOverlay and ViewGroupOverlay, GroundOverlayOptions classes only.